# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. error for excel

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oledb, excel-2010, oledbconnection, oledbexception

[image]

i use windows 7 home basic 64-bit and microsoft excel starter 2010 and i want to read an excel file but when i debug my code, i take this error: `The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.` 
my code is the followings:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource=getirExcel();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
DataTable getirExcel()
{
    string dosya_adres = @"C:\Users\Erdi\Downloads\DBE_BAKIM_FORMU.xlsx";
    OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + dosya_adres + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0");
    baglanti.Open();
    string query = "select * from [Sheet1$A1:D20]";
    OleDbDataAdapter oAdp = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, baglanti);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    oAdp.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

i have tried `Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0` but it does not work for 64-bit according to forums. do you know any alternative provider?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the database engine here:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255